# merge sql statement from 2 databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to merge 2 tables from 2 databases on 2 differents servers.

For now, I create a linked server on one of the servers and I use a query like this:

```
MERGE INTO tablename1 as T1  
using linkedservername.dbname.tablename2 as T2  ON  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
   UPDATE SET ... 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
   INSERT ...
```

I would like to know if there is a solution to do that without create a linked server.

Comment: Is Replication an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I use this query in a SSIS package, and the structure of 2 tables are not the same.

Comment: Would [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx) be of use? Topic is: _Ad Hoc Distributed Queries_

Comment: I have the same question with the merge join : is it possible to use it in this case without use a linked server? Can I create a connection to a distant server in a query?

Comment: It's possible to build all of this logic in SSIS (without a linked table). I'll add an SSIS tag as this is a pretty important piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

There are three general ways to do this in SSIS. But there is a lot more information if you check online.

Either way you first need to create a connection manager in SSIS pointing directly at your linked server. Start with that.

Then create a data flow task where you `select from dbname.tablename2` in a data flow source

Then you can do it a few ways:

A. Staging Table

Dump that result into a staging table then run your merge statement locally in a subsequent SQL Task. This is usually the quickest (and simplest) way unless you aren't allowed to create tables/data in the target.

B. Lookup

Use a lookup in your data flow to identify if the record exists or not, followed by a OLEDB destination (for inserts) or a OLEDB command (for updates)

This is generally slow because both the lookup and update are inefficient.

C. row level merge

Feed the result into a OLEDB command, and put your merge directly in there

This is probably the slowest.

If you want more info, get your connection manager sorted and post back.

Comment: I already tried all of this ssis solutions and they are so slowly with big table. I've created custom task ssis which use sql merge statement and it's work fine. But I'm obligated to create a linked db when my 2 tables are not on the same server. Therefore my question.

Comment: Did you try the staged method (1) ? that should be the fastest. Stage all the data locally. Run one update query and one insert query. Optimise indexes for you inserts and updates

Comment: Sorry but my question is not "how to do that in ssis". I know how to do it in ssis, thank's. I don't know who add the flag ssis to my question but it's a mistake. My question concerning only sql statement.

Comment: I added the flag. It indicates this is the tools you have at your disposal. So your constraints are that you cannot use a linked server and you cannot use SSIS? Please indicate in the question.

Comment: Also you specifically asked above if you could use a merge join (SSIS)

Comment: If you don't want to use SSIS or linked servers you could use BCP/flat files, message queue, replication. How big is the table and can you create a staging table on the target